# mutivariable unconstrained optimization using gradient search procedure

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, operations-research, gradient-flows

Multi-variable unconstrained optimization problem:  
Maximize the function,  
$$f(x)=2xy+2y-x^2-2y^2$$ using the gradient search procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the other method that your teacher wants, but this is slicker...$f(x,y) = -(x-y)^2 - (y-1)^2 + 1 \leq 1 \Rightarrow f_{\text{max}} = 1$ when $x = y = 1$.

Note: The trick is "completing square".

Comment: nice answer @kf-sansoo. can you please elaborate it further. the solution is short cut.